# Organizing project components — does this need to be alphabetic?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React project built in a framework called ARc (https://arc.js.org). It uses something called "atomic design" to arrange the components. The tree looks like this…

`/components/atoms
/components/molecules
/components/organisms
/components/pages`

… where atoms are very primitive components (inputs, buttons), molecules are compound primitives (say an input plus a label and a feedback message component), organisms are collections of molecules (say, a form), and pages which are hopefully self-explanatory.

I like it quite a lot, but it hasn't scaled very well for our project. We're now at ~100 components, and would prefer to break this stuff down into folders like "accounts" and "checkout".

As a first step, I renamed our "atoms" folder to "primitives" and "molecules" to "widgets", and everything broke pretty much immediately. I found that by naming them "_primitives" and "_widgets" things would go back to normal, but… this can't be right, can it? Does webpack work alphabetically? Does the Atomic React thing only work because "atoms, molecules, organisms, pages" are words that are in alphabetical order??

Comment: Please, show up your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Nearly unchanged from this: https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: When you say you renamed the folders, did you also update all the import paths everywhere in the project? If you did, and it did not work, than the only thing I can think of is if you are using babel-plugin-module-resolver to have shortcuts in your imports. Are you using it?

Comment: All components import from 'components', there weren't any paths in the first place.

Comment: The ordering of folder should not matter and if it really does then it is probably a bug in the source/packages that you are using. There might be something else also happening here also, so without a reproducible sample its hard to say what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be due to a peculiarity in the specific React framework that I was using. It preloads components into an object for easy retrieval. This works in ARc because it uses a bottom-up sequence that guarantees that a dependent component will already be loaded, but falls apart if the order isn't quite right.

Not a webpack issue. Thank those of you who took a few minutes to be stumped on this.

https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/issues/343